# How to find sudo password in Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I'm using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3 desktop. I don't know my sudo password so I'm unable to do `sudo` operations.

How do I find my password or change it?

Answer (score 2):

In System Preferences, select Users & Groups, then change password on your user.

Comment: ThankU for the answer. Finally I did it. I created a password for my account and from "su" command, i changed the permissions of the root file and edited it. I got the result what i want.